# StandardTitanGraph java.lang.Throwable: Hook creation trace error

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am getting the below exception (Titan + cassandra) in my scala project running in windows

> DEBUG c.t.t.g.database.StandardTitanGraph - Installed shutdown hook
>   Thread[Thread-9,5,main] java.lang.Throwable: Hook creation trace  at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.(StandardTitanGraph.java:156)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:74)
>   [titan-core-1.0.0.jar:na]     at
>   notificaiton.UEReportReceiver$.connect_graph_db(UEReportReceiver.scala:62)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   notificaiton.UEReportReceiver.inserttoDB(UEReportReceiver.scala:159)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   notificaiton.UEReportReceiver$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UEReportReceiver.scala:139)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]   at
>   notificaiton.UEReportReceiver.aroundReceive(UEReportReceiver.scala:130)
>   [classes/:na]     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]   at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]   at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
>   [akka-actor_2.11-2.3.15.jar:na]   at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>   [scala-library-2.11.0.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>   [scala-library-2.11.0.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>   [scala-library-2.11.0.jar:na]     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   [scala-library-2.11.0.jar:na]

Anything am i missing ? Could you please help

Comment: When does this happen ? Could you provide some sample code which leads to this error ?

Answer (score 3):

The stack trace is harmless. A Throwable is included in a [DEBUG message](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/graphdb/database/StandardTitanGraph.java#L156).

[This issue](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1242) has come up before. There is a [dependency conflict](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/titan10/titan-cassandra/pom.xml#L44-L62) between 2 different logging systems: slf4j and logback. In its Maven build and `gremlin.sh`, Titan attempts to enforce a classpath order to keep slf4j ahead of logback. You could take the same approach when building your Scala application.

Alternatively, another [workaround](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/tZ0XhwJY9jQ/Ry2GmTtWAgAJ) is to include a `logback.xml` file on the classpath:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```