# How To Setup JanusGraph Cassandra On Docker

Tags: cassandra-3.0, docker-container, janusgraph, java-17, gremlin-server

## Problem

With Docker containers, how do setup [Apache Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/index.html) to work with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)? 
I need to setup an external [JanusGraph](https://docs.janusgraph.org/) to handle tens of millions of records.
I'm new to Cassandra, JanusGraph, and [Graph-Databases](https://www.g2.com/categories/graph-databases) in-general.

## Repo Steps

1. Download-and-Install [Docker [Program]](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph)
2. Create-and-Startup [JanusGraph [Docker-container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/)

   ```bash
   docker run -d -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph
   ```
3. Create-and-Startup [Apache Cassandra [Docker-container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/)

   ```bash
   docker run --name jg-cassandra -d -e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true -p 9160:9160 
      -p 9042:9042 -p 7199:7199 -p 7001:7001 -p 7000:7000 cassandra:3.11
   ```
4. Code-and-Run test to connect to [Cassandra container](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra) for JanusGraph instance

   ```java
   JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
   ```
5. Results

   1. Expected: [`JanusGraphFactory`-instance](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.4.0/org/janusgraph/core/JanusGraphFactory.html) to connect to Cassandra-docker-container
   2. Actual: Error

```bash
java.lang.Throwable: Hook creation trace
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:250) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:176) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:147) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:137) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory$Builder.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:277) [janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240.jar:?]
    at Main.main(Main.java:10) [classes/:?]
```

```java
// Main
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- pom.xml -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230424-065649.dcd3240</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-cql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230428-082704.5159135</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image: Cassandra seems to have JanusGraph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That stack trace is for debugging purposes and is not an error. See [StandardTitanGraph java.lang.Throwable: Hook creation trace error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737886/standardtitangraph-java-lang-throwable-hook-creation-trace-error)